# Matlab - selecting Only Numbers from a sentence with Text & Numbers

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I have a very large text file like this

```
[1] score in three tests in math    :stud1 = 28 26 23
[2] score in three tests in science :stud1 = 23 28 30
[3] score in three tests in english :stud1 = 25 23 27
[4] score in three tests in history :stud1 = 27 24 21
& so on.
```

I want to collect all the numbers in the text file and arrange in a table like this -

```
 stud1
28 26 23
23 28 30
25 23 27
27 24 21
```

Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to go about this. Here is one way to do it using the [str2num](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) function:

```
table = [];
test = '[1] score in three tests in math    :stud1 = 28 26 23';

pos = strfind(test,'='); %find the '=' token
if(pos > 0) 
    subStr = test(pos+1:end); %get the sub string
    row = str2num(subStr);    %parse the row
    table(end+1,:) = row;     %append the row to your table 
end
```